# write a function that works with int or enum parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I'm trying to write a function that will take either any form of int or enum.
I've tried to provide two versions:

```
template<typename E>int bit_num (const E bitPatA)
template<typename E>int bit_num (enum bitPatA)
```

The enum version does not compile.

I've found is_enum and enable_if but have been unable to come up with an incantation to do the following:

```
template <typename E>int bit_num <E bitPatA)
{
if is_enum typedef typename std::underlying_type<E>::type int_T;
if !is_enum typedef E int_T;
...
}
```

All the examples of is_enum appear to just print out text rather than do something useful like control the generation of templates.

I have found that a union will do part of what I want to do

```
<template E>int bit_num (E bitPatA)
{
union {uintmax_t i; enum e;} bitpat;

bitPat.i = 0;       // clear cruft
bitPat.e = bitPatA; // load from enum

                    // use from int
if ((bitPat.i == 0) || ((bitPat.i & ~(bitPat.i - 1)) != bitPat.i)) return -1;
...
}
```

but this doesn't allow me to get the underlying kind of int.

I want to explore the compiler optimizations for various sizes.

---

[Code and error from comment]

```
using namespace std;

int bit_num (const enum bitPatA)
{
    return -1;
}

template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    using type=T;
};

template <typename E>
typename enable_if< /* is_enum<E>{} ||*/ is_integral<E>{}, int>::type
bit_num (const E bitPatA)
{
    return -1;
}
```

error is

```
||=== Build: Debug in Bit_num (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| /home/jfw/Documents/Bit_num/BitTools.cpp|13|error: use of enum ‘bitPatA’ without previous declaration|
```

Comment: If you tell us the error, and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us how you use the functions, then we will be better able to help you.

Comment: If you are using C++11, then you could try looking into [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) and [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) to limit generation

Comment: @Joachim using namespace std;
    int bit_num (const enum bitPatA) { return -1; }
    template <typename T> struct identity {using type=T;};
    template <typename E>
    typename enable_if< /* is_enum<E>{} ||*/ is_integral<E>{}, int>::type     bit_num (const E bitPatA)
    {
        return -1;
    } error is ||=== Build: Debug in Bit_num (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/jfw/Documents/Bit_num/BitTools.cpp|13|error: use of enum ‘bitPatA’ without previous declaration|

Comment: Please read that error message again, it's very clear if you just remember that everything in C++ must be declared before its used.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) in combination with [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>{} || std::is_integral<T>{}, int>::type
 bit_num (T t);
```

This function will only be a candidate in overload resolution if the argument is of enumeration or integral type.

The typedef you're trying to set up in your question can be implemented using a helper trait:

```
template <typename T> struct identity {using type=T;};
```

Usage would be

```
using int_T = typename std::conditional<std::is_enum<T>{}, 
                                        std::underlying_type<E>,
                                        identity<E>>::type::type;
```

Comment: Columbo Thanks,  Your suggestion using enable_if does indeed prevent generating the function for non-appropriate types (e.g.: float).

Comment: I'm still trying to generate "typedef E int_T" if !is_enum and if is_enum"typedef underlying_type<E> int_T".  I tried what you suggested using two "using" statements, one with "is_enum" and the other with "!is_enum" but I got "error: conflicting declaration 'using int_T =' with references to each using statement.  How do I generate one typdef for is_enum and another for !is_enum?  Thanks

Comment: I wonder if just writing `std::underlying_type<int>` is enough for UB, or if you'd have to do something that causes its instantiation for it to be UB.

Comment: @T.C. [res.on.functions]/(2.3) explicitly talks about instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to all (@columbo, @joachim), here is what I have as my code using some of your suggestions:

```
using namespace std;
template <typename T> struct identity {using type=T;};

template <typename E>
typename enable_if<is_integral<E>{}, int>::type bit_num (const E bitPatA)
{
    using int_T = E;
                                                // ignore truncation warnings for mask*
    const int_T mask1 = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALLU;  // bits under mask position contains 1
    const int_T mask2 = 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCLLU;  // bits under mask position contains 2
    const int_T mask3 = 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0LLU;
    const int_T mask4 = 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00LLU;
    const int_T mask5 = 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000LLU;
    const int_T mask6 = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000LLU;  // bits under mask position contains 32
    size_t      sum = 0;                        // accumulator and return value
    int         bit = 1;                        // sliding bit position value

    // return error if no bits or more than one
    if ((bitPatA == 0) || ((bitPatA & ~(bitPatA - 1)) != bitPatA)) return --sum;

    sum += (mask1 & bitPatA) ? bit : 0;         // if non-zero under mask, add bit value
    bit <<= 1;                                  // multiply bit by 2
    sum += (mask2 & bitPatA) ? bit : 0;
    bit <<= 1;
    sum += (mask3 & bitPatA) ? bit : 0;
    if (mask4 == 0) return sum;                 // are the rest of the tests nugatory?
    bit <<= 1;
    sum += (mask4 & bitPatA) ? bit : 0;
    if (mask5 == 0) return sum;
    bit <<= 1;
    sum += (mask5 & bitPatA) ? bit : 0;
    if (mask6 == 0) return sum;
    bit <<= 1;
    sum += (mask6 & bitPatA) ? bit : 0;
    return sum;
}

template <typename E>
typename enable_if<is_enum<E>{}, int>::type bit_num (const E bitPatA)
{
    using int_T = typename conditional<is_enum<E>{}, underlying_type<E>, identity<E> >::type::type;
    return bit_num (static_cast<int_T>(bitPatA));
}
```

The first version of bit_num() works with integer type, the second with enum types.  The second casts the argument to an integer and calls the first.

I now understand that int bit_num (const enum foo) is parsed as a constant "enum foo", not as a "const enum" parameter named "foo".

I still don't understand how to conditionally place one of both definitions of int_T in a single version of bit_num(), but using the second bit_num() that is generated only for enum arguments and passes the argument value and *type* does what I need.